# How to insert multiple rows of paypal ipn variables to mysql database

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am creating a shopping cart with paypal checkout. I want that the ipn to insert rows to mysql after transaction.

For now , it does just that , but it only intersects one row even if there  were more than 3 different items in the cart.
I guess I need a foreach loop so each item from the cart gets its own database row after transaction.

I have tried but cant  get any working.
here is example of the results i log to a file

```
 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=7.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=&tax=0.00&item_number2=&payer_id=SLDWABVPR4W3N&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=01%3A56%3A35+Jul+30%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&mc_shipping=0.00&mc_handling=0.00&first_name=test&mc_fee=0.50&address_country_code=US&address_name=test+buyer&notify_version=3.8&custom=5-1%2C3-1%2C&payer_status=verified&business=ericel123-facilitator%40gmail.com&address_country=United+States&num_cart_items=2&mc_handling1=0.00&mc_handling2=0.00&address_city=San+Jose&verify_sign=Agvo6..302dNn6xS6bIzJdaQQfJ7AnGucvHS6CgM0lgL0w5Q5Oz8VCI-&payer_email=ericel123-buyer%40gmail.com&mc_shipping1=0.00&mc_shipping2=0.00&tax1=0.00&tax2=0.00&txn_id=8YJ42821LM735725U&payment_type=instant&last_name=buyer&address_state=CA&item_name1=white+cup&receiver_email=ericel123-facilitator%40gmail.com&item_name2=Men+handy+bags&payment_fee=0.50&quantity1=1&quantity2=1&receiver_id=KET4YMZ2YCVY8&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=2.00&mc_currency=USD&mc_gross_2=5.00&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&transaction_subject=5-1%2C3-1%2C&payment_gross=7.00&ipn_track_id=8b6b5bb9131
```

The above is from this foreach loop.

```
  foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
```

How can I create an array for selected variables I need and be able to create or insert records base on item_name or item_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of the IPN data you would just use $_POST['varname'] to pull the value.  For order items you can use the following to parse all of the items into $cart_items.

```
$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```

Then you could loop through $cart_items to process each individual item accordingly.  Here's an example of what you might do.

```
foreach($cart_items as $item)
{
    $db->prepare("INSERT INTO s_itms_trans(item_number, item_name, mc_gross) VALUES('".$item['item_number']."', '".$item['item_name']."', ".$item['mc_gross'].")")->execute();
}
```

Comment: Angelll, thanks. My biggest problem is the insert statement. And what is with the $option_name1, and option_selection1 and btn_id? I didn't have that in my paypal parse POST variables.

Comment: This simply handles any parameter that could be available based on the type of transaction and the type of items that were included.  If the parameter isn't in the IPN POST then it simply gets a blank value here.  Not sure what you mean that your problem is the insert statement..??  I don't see any insert statement in your original post.

Comment: `code`$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `s_itms_trans`(item_number, item_name, product_id_array, mc_gross) VALUES(".$cart_items.")")->execute();`code` I want to be able to insert the orders to my transaction table, with each item occupying its own row. So let say there were two items in the shopping cart, after transaction the two different rows will be inserted into mysql database.

Comment: Then you would loop through the $cart_items array that the code I supplied would give you based on the IPN data.